# Android NDK: Aborting stop?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, makefile, ffmpeg

I am working on ffmpeg for android. I have successfully compile ffmpeg-2.0.1 
         after that I make  Android.mk file in my NDK's sources/ffmpeg-2.0.1/android/arm as

```
      LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

      include $(CLEAR_VARS)

      LOCAL_MODULE:= libavcodec

      LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavcodec-55.so

       LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

      include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

After that make android project and in android project Android.mk file is as

```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := tutorial01
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial01.c
   LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz 
   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    $(call import-module,ffmpeg-2.0.1/android/arm)
```

but showing a problem

```
 *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
   android-ffmpeg-tutorial01line 45, external location: 
   /home/tech/Documents/roman10/ndk/android-ndk-r9c/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk
   C/C++ Problem
```

My NDK is android-ndk-r9c,system is ubuntu-13.04,please anyone guide me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u already solved this problem?

Comment: Sorry ,I unable to solved this issue ,Can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [`Android.mk structure`](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html) firstly.

Need change `Android.mk` file like this :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/ffmpeg.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := final_ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_PREBUILTS := libs/ffmpeg.so
#libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

*p/s :
I also get the `Android NDK : Aborting` problem as you when put data together like this :*

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= libs/ffmpeg.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ffmpeg
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

*This problem happens when* `LOCAL_MODULE` *name is duplicated.*

The result will help you :

It still be exactly when you need [call the C++ function in C++ file from Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607042/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-calling-c-method-in-c-file-from-java-file?noredirect=1#comment34431151_22607042).

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar problem when I tried to build HelloComputeNDK sample with NDK64-Linux-r10.

Then I notice that NDK64-Linux-r10 only have Android-L platform, so I download NDK32-Linux-R10, and merge it with NDK64-Linux-r10.

It goes well for me.

U can download NDK32-Linux-r10 here:
https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue resolved just by moving the project folder from [E:\folder\subfolder] to [E:]  only.