# Android NDK w/ ffmpeg library - error running project

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

Using this guide, http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/, I successfully compiled ffmpeg-2.4.2 with Android NDK 10, but now I'm having issues using it in my eclipse project.

The error I'm getting:

```
*** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

which points to this in prebuilt-library.mk:

```
ifndef prebuilt
$(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE): LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file)
$(call __ndk_info,Check that $(prebuilt_path) exists, or that its path is correct)
$(call __ndk_error,Aborting) <----- ***** This line is specifically pointed out by the error log
endif
```

Here's my ...jni/Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := VideoTest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := videotest.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -landroid
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,ffmpeg-2.4.2/android/arm)
```

Here's my android-ndk/sources/ffmpeg-2.4.2/android/arm/Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavcodec-55.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavformat-55.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libswscale-2.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavutil-52.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavfilter-3.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libwsresample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libswresample-0.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here's my project structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfjYJ.jpg

So it seems to me that the project isn't building because the LOCAL_SRC_FILES doesn't point to anything, but is it referring to LOCAL_SRC_FILES in jni/Android.mk or the one in ...ffmpeg-2.4.2/android/arm/Android.mk? Either way, it seems like they are actually pointing to something. I've also tried looking at this solution, [Android NDK: Aborting stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526992/android-ndk-aborting-stop), but I'm having a hard time understanding it. Which Android.mk file needs changing?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve your problem? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg 2.4.2 uses newer libraries:

libavcodec-56.so,
libavformat-56.so,
libswscale-3.so,
libavutil-54.so,
libavfilter-5.so,
libswresample-1.so

UPDATE:
and i think you've got a typo in android-ndk/sources/ffmpeg-2.4.2/android/arm/Android.mk. 4th line from the end - it should be `LOCAL_MODULE:= libswresample`

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure and build commands seem fine to me. I would suggest some points to try: 
1. Try adding an Application.mk file in jni. 
2. Try building the VideoTest.so in linux environment with linux ndk and maybe with a lower and stable version of ndk.